# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'authentication' was called on null [GoogleAPI + YoutubeAPI + Firebase + Flutter]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-api, youtube-api

I´m facing this issue, it looks like my auth var is null, but I don't see any issues. Error:

```
E/flutter (24944): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'authentication' was called on null.
E/flutter (24944): Receiver: null
E/flutter (24944): Tried calling: authentication
E/flutter (24944): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
```

My Code (just the function with problem):

```
  addPlayListItem(String videoID, String playlistID) async {
    final String apiUrl =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet";
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        'email',
        'profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
      ],
    );

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(currentUser.uid == user.uid);

    void signOutGoogle() async {
      await googleSignIn.signOut();
    }

    print("token  " +
        googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken); // accessToken not idToken

    final response = await http.post(
      apiUrl,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer ${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken}",
        // Use access token and add a space after the 'Bearer
        "Accept": "application/json",
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        "snippet": {
          "playlistId": "" + playlistID,
          "resourceId": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "" + videoID}
        }
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Song was added to playlist");
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      print("Failture song wasn't added to playlist");
    }
  }
```

This is the ErrorCode I get, when im trying to use the function on an iOS device. Maybe this gives more informations.

```
2021-09-11 11:58:53.310702+0200 Runner[6447:55089] flutter: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
2021-09-11 11:58:53.310854+0200 Runner[6447:55089] flutter: Failture song wasn't added to playlist
```

It seems like I have an authentication problem, but I don't know where to start to find it.

Update Android:
after a clean rebuild I've got this error code

```
E/flutter ( 3537): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)
E/flutter ( 3537): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter ( 3537): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter ( 3537): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3537): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)
E/flutter ( 3537): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3537): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:233:30)
E/flutter ( 3537): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3537): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter ( 3537): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3537):
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the [signInSilently](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignIn/signInSilently.html) method:

> Attempts to sign in a previously authenticated user without
> interaction.
>
> Returned `Future` resolves to an instance of `GoogleSignInAccount` for a
> successful sign in or `null` if there is no previously authenticated
> user. Use `signIn` method to trigger interactive sign in process.

So you're getting `googleSignInAccount` as `null` because there was no previously signed in user.

You can add a check to see if the `googleSignInAccount` is `null` and use `signIn` if true.

So you can update this:

```dart
...
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
...
```

to this:

```dart
...
GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();

if (googleSignAccount == null) {
  googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
}
...
```

Comment: I added this, well now just a window opens up and keeps loading when I try to call this function.

Comment: You should wrap your code with a `try-catch` and print the error in the catch block. There might be an error preventing it from continuing.

Comment: well even though its still the same error as mention in my question

Comment: Could you clarify? Does it open the window now and what shows up on it?

Comment: well its the notification window from google I guess where u have to accept the permissions, but it just keeps loading.

Comment: @JayProXter Are you calling `signInSilently()` in all your requests to get a new token?

Comment: @JideGuru this is the only request im calling signInSilently()

Comment: it keeps loading like in this picture 
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/50893442/64466814-c6de3a00-d0c8-11e9-9263-2528b8d285af.png

Comment: Maybe useful to know, I changed the fingerprint in firebase, and it stopped working after it. But the google SignIn from firebase is still working, just this function won't work.

Comment: @JayProXter Just a thought, have you tried flutter clean and also reinstalling the app?

Comment: Yes I already did, it’s werid. Any other ideas ?